# Destructuring declaration in Kotlin results in type errors

Tags: android, kotlin, destructuring

In the code below, when I call `holder.imgAvatar.setImageResource(avatar)`, it says that my variable (`avatar`) is `String`, even though I already set it to `Int` in the data class.

Why is this happening?

ListUserAdapter.kt

```
class ListUserAdapter(val listUser: ArrayList<User>) {
    // ...
    fun someMethod() {
        val (name, username, avatar) = listUser[position]
        holder.imgAvatar.setImageResource(avatar)
        holder.tvName.text = name
        holder.tvUserName.text = username
```

User.kt

```
@Parcelize
data class User(
    var username: String,
    var name: String,
    var location: String,
    var company: String,
    var repository: String,
    var followers: String,
    var following: String,
    var avatar:Int,
):Parcelable
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Destructuring declarations **are not based on the variable names** but rather on consequential calls to the `componentN()` method of the `data class`.

What I mean by that is that Your code:

```kotlin
val (name, username, avatar) = listUser[position]
```

Does not mean:

```kotlin
val name = listUser[position].name
val username = listUser[position].username
val avatar = listUser[position].avatar
```

But it means:

```kotlin
val name = listUser[position].component1()
val username = listUser[position].component2()
val avatar = listUser[position].component3()
```

Which can be understood as:

```kotlin
val name = listUser[position].username
val username = listUser[position].name
val avatar = listUser[position].location
```

So the `avatar` value gets the value of the `location` from the `listUser[position]`.

You should rather get the reference to the `User` that You need from the list and basically assign the values yourself. Or You can change the order of the values of the `User` `data class`.

You can read on the *destructuring declarations* more [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/destructuring-declarations.html).

Comment: oh! i see i see,ive tried it and it works,thank you